# P value in lmer

Tags: lme4, p-value

My data frame is like:

```
 DOY EWMZ TREE
 24   54   1
 22   65   1
 30   47   1
 35   44   1
 24   65   2
 22   64   2
 30   62   2
 35   70   2
```

I did the lmer as following and i need to find the P value for my mixed effect model but i dont know the P value of my model is the one for intercept or DOY?

```
Model.1 <- lmer(EWMZ ~ DOY + (1 | TREE), data = Df)

coefs <- data.frame(coef(summary(Model.1)))
coefs$p.z <- 2 * (1 - pnorm(abs(coefs$t.value)))

               Estimate Std..Error   t.value       p.z       p.KR
(Intercept) 18.536192984 9.56298373 1.9383274 0.0525833 0.05884826
DOY          0.006558046 0.03328486 0.1970279 0.8438057 0.84468965
```

Comment: What is your question? p-values are displayed for both the intercept and DOY. In the future, you can use `lmerTest` to get better p-values that use Satterthwaite approximation. I have never seen someone calculate p-values for fixed effects like you have done above.

Comment: ok thank you i will try it